# CSS Text effect white background

Tags: css

I would like to add a white background to my letters.

I have an image as example, but I would like to build this image with CSS.

[image: home button]

To see the difference, edit html with editor and add black as body background.

I have tried this with text-shadow, but it didn't work great.
My question is how can I build this with css?

Kind regards,

Itouch

Comment: `text-shadow` *does* work great. Please show your attempt

Comment: [This article](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) is for you and [this one](http://thisischris.com/archives/2012/08/outlining-your-text-or-fun-with-css-text-shadows/) is also helpful.

Comment: `text-stroke` is webkit only though - http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that text-shadow is the only way to go.
something like :

```
text-shadow: -1px 0 #fff, 0 1px #fff, 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px #fff
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/zGxdMQ

Comment: This looks pretty ugly if you want to have 3px outline. Is there any solution for thicker outline?

Comment: @skobaljic I don't think so, unfortunately

Comment: Don't know, how would you make the white outline thickness to say 3px? I tried in Firefox without success. I also noticed webkit renders the shadow some other way.

Comment: @skobaljic As far as I know, you can't do it in CSS. If you really need to manipulate some text in advanced way, try to use a js lib like http://letteringjs.com/ .

Comment: There is a way (look answer below) to somehow make it work in css, just wondering if there is some better way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which is not really answering your question but still it might help (i hope).

You can make use of SVG and `stroke-linejoin`.

```
<svg height="100" width="250">
  <text 
        x="0" 
        y="50" 
        fill="red"
        stroke="#ffffff"
        stroke-width="3px"
        font-size="50px"
        letter-spacing="-4"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        font-weight="600">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/zemeya/2/edit?html,css,output

Edit: I changed the font to be more funky adding this line between head tags.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually stroke-linecap is not needed

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of `text-shadow` and `letter-spacing`.

First of all you need to get a solid "border" around your text.
For that use this:

```
text-shadow:-1px 0 #fff, 0 1px #fff, 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px #fff,
            -2px 0 #fff, 0 2px #fff, 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px #fff
```

But that's not all. As there is another shadow which is kinda blurry you have to add another text-shadow:

```
text-shadow:-1px 0 #fff, 0 1px #fff, 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px #fff,
            -2px 0 #fff, 0 2px #fff, 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px #fff,
            2px 2px 3px #000;
```

Now you may remove some letter-spacing. You can do this by use a nagative value for it:

```
letter-spacing: -6px;
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy);

span {
    font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
    letter-spacing: -6px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#555;
    text-shadow:-1px 0 #fff,
    0 1px #fff,
    1px 0 #fff,
    0 -1px #fff,
    -2px 0 #fff,
    0 2px #fff,
    2px 0 #fff,
    0 -2px #fff,
    2px 2px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<span>home</span>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8f5y98/)

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [text-shadow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-shadow/) property, but than you would have to stack values to achieve thicker stroke this way:

```css
body {
 background-color: #ddd;
}
p {
 font-size: 52px;
 color: #666666;
 text-shadow: 0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,0 0 3px #fff,
  4px 4px 6px #000, 4px 4px 6px #000;
}
```

```html
<p>home</p>
```

Also on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwYvxZ).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a colored outline on text by using the text-shadow in CSS. The trick is you have to do multiple shadows:

```
.white_background {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff,
    0px 0px 1px #fff,
    0px 0px 1px #fff,
    0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

CSS supports multiple listings of text-shadow. Each listing stacks with the others. If you stack up enough, they give the appearance of a solid outline.

Comment: @jbutler483 you could consider removing the downvote